# converting each sas dataset to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting the each sas dataset from the list of directory to individual dataframe in pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat as pyd
os.chdir(r'XX\XX\XX\XXX')
```

Assume the default directory contains the list of sasdatsets.

```
aa.sas7bdat
bb.sas7bdat
cc.sas7bdat
dd.sas7bdat
ee.sas7bdat
```

Now i am creating the dictionary where it iterates each sas datasets using `pyd.read_sas7bdat` import into the individual data frame.

```
 ddict={}
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(".sas7bdat"):
            name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            ddict[name]=pyd.read_sas7bdat(file,metadataonly=False)
```

But i am still not able to succeed with the above code and pls help how to achieve. My output expected was to create new dataframe for each sasdatasets i,e there shall be multiple dataframes Note: dataframe should be the name of the sasdatasets without the extension

> for example  aa.sas7bdat --> sas datasets aa --> to be created as
> dataframe

Comment: There `pd.read_sas` function.

Comment: here my objective not on function, I want to mulitple dataframe for each sas dataset. let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import os

import pyreadstat as pyd

ddict={}

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".sas7bdat"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        df, meta = pyd.read_sas7bdat(file)
        # store the dataframe in a dictionary
        ddict[name]= df
        # alternatively bind to a new variable name
        exec(name + "= df.copy()")
```

Remember that read_sas7bdat gives you a tuple of dataframe and metadata object, not a dataframe only.

Comment: If i want to create multiple dataframe Which should be the name of the each sasdatasets without the extension? Is this pyreadstat helps

Comment: Ok, if I understand your comment correctly, you don't want the dataframes to be stored in a dictionary but to create a variable for each, where the variable name is the name of the file? I edit my answer to reflect that.